# How to copy cell values from one dataframe to another (mismatched dataframe length)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames of unequal length:

```
Cat Count   Count03
A   17469   0
B   2327    0
C   7649    0
D   11496   0
E   26      0
F   1996    0
G   175     0
H   2914    0
I   486     0
J   0       0
K   4052    0
```

```
Cat Count   Count03
A   0       480
B   0       34
C   0       234
E   0       56
F   0       4545
G   0       44
I   0       112
J   0       12
K   0       1
```

I would like to merge the values in df2.Count03 into df1.Count03 as shown in the df1.updated dataframe.

```
Cat Count   Count03
A   17469   480
B   2327    34
C   7649    234
D   11496   0
E   26      56
F   1996    4545
G   175     44
H   2914    0
I   486     112
J   0       12
K   4052    1
```

The challenge I am facing is that because the dataframes are of unequal length means that outer and inner joins dont seem to work as required. I am wonder if there is an elegant approach to copy values from one cell across dataframes?

In terms of approach i was thinking of the following (IMHO ugly approach). Pseudo code below:

```
      copy contents of df2.count03 to df1.count3

else
      assign a value of 0
```

Any tips to how i could approach a solution to this problem is much appreciated.

Thanks
Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with aggregate `sum`, it working weel because same columns names in both `DataFrame`s:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('Cat', as_index=False).sum()
print (df)
   Cat  Count  Count03
0    A  17469      480
1    B   2327       34
2    C   7649      234
3    D  11496        0
4    E     26       56
5    F   1996     4545
6    G    175       44
7    H   2914        0
8    I    486      112
9    J      0       12
10   K   4052        1
```

Comment: Many thanks @jezrael, your solution is very elegant.